# Reloads page once then reloads again without content change

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, reload

I have a  bit of javascript that posts to a php, every second, which checks a schedule and basically returns "refresh" if the start time is met then returns refresh when the end time is met.

if "refresh" it reloads the page showing what its suppose to.

```
function checkSchedules(){
  if(sch_timer)
    clearInterval(sch_timer)
 $.ajax({
  url:'checkSchedule_test.php?mediaID='+mediaIDArray[schCount],
  type:'GET',
  complete: function (response) {

       if(response.responseText == "refresh"){
           location.reload(true);
       }          

  },
  error: function () {
      alert('Sorry there was an error!');
  },
})
sch_timer = setTimeout(checkSchedules,1000);
schCount = (schCount >= urlArray.length - 1)? -1 : schCount
++schCount
}
```

in the php

```
if ($current_date>=$startDate && $current_date<=$endDate){
    if ($current_time >= $startTime && $current_time <= $endTime){
 $timeout = $endTime - $current_time;
 if ($current_time >= $startTime && $current_time <= ($startTime+3000)){
    echo "refresh";
 }
if($timeout<=3000){
    echo "refresh";
}
    }
}
```

when the start time is met it refreshes fine, works great. 
then when the end time is met it refreshes but the contents the same.
if I hit refresh it works fine.

I've tried different methods of reload() (document.reload, etc...)

Has anyone got any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: You can do this all via JS, why are you checking date/time via php?

Comment: the php gets the set times from the DB, so I either return the times and do the math JS or do it all in PHP return true or false. both have the same result.

Comment: You are creating an instance with a gigantic overhead, say you have 1000 users each checking you site every second to do some date/time calculations, now your server is clogged up with all these requests.  Set up some JSON which contains a start/end time for each item and loop through it when a time is it then and only then make a call to the server to refresh that one object and not the whole page.

Comment: looking at it I agree, I've converted into JS using JSON. I'm yet to get to the refresh part.

Answer (score 0):

use console to understand what is returning from server

use `debug()` or `console.log()` for understand what is returning from php ... reload script is correct issue will be during ajax

Comment: it does trigger a refresh or an alert() at the end time.